# Is there a way I can recover my files from a Kingston DataTravler 1GB?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, file-recovery

I accidentally started to low format my USB stick, then I removed it in panic, now when I insert my USB stick in my computer, it displays as "USB DISK 30X" instead of "Kingston DataTraveler 2.0" and it says that I need to format it before I can use it.
Whenever I use a recovery tool like "EaseUS: Free Data Recovery" it says it didn't find any raw files. I came across with testdisk and this is what I got:

```
 Select a media (use Arrow keys, then press Enter):
 Disk /dev/sda - 250 GB / 232 GiB - ST3250310CS
>Disk /dev/sdc - 1027 MB / 980 MiB - USB DISK 30X
 Drive H: - 673 MB / 642 MiB - DTSOFT BDROM
```

Is there anything else I can do?

```
Disk /dev/sdc - 1027 MB / 980 MiB - CHS 124 255 63
Current partition structure:
     Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors


Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55
No partition found or selected for recovery
```

UPDATE

```
Disk /dev/sdb - 1027 MB / 980 MiB (RO) - USB DISK 30X
Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
P Unknown                  0   0  1   124 237 49    2007040


0 files saved in /Nueva carpeta/recover/recup_dir directory.
Recovery completed.
```

I just tried photorec, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Can you better describe what you did to "initiate a low level format".

Assuming that the first part of the disk has been erased by overwriting it, testdisk probably won't help much, but you will probably have some luck with Photorec  (Part of the same suite of tools).  Photorec won't recover names of files, but it scans the disk for file signatures and trys to recreate files - which is quite good for things like photos, but works on other documents as well.  [ How well it works depends on fragmentation and other considerations ]

Comment: I ran a program called "Repair_v2.9.1.1.exe", but I didn't notice it was formatting my Kensington USB stick. I was looking for a way to format another USB stick because it has copyright protection.

Comment: @MaQleod I just tried Photorec, but it didn't find a single file.

Comment: Sorry to deliver the bad news, but your data is gone.

Comment: Is there at least a way to make it display "Kingston DataTraveler" instead of "USB DISK 30X"?

Comment: What OS? You can typically reformat with a label or sometimes change the label at the command line.

Comment: Windows 7, but I think is more like the firmware in my usb stick or something like that. I haven't formatted it yet, but I'm not sure if it's going to work like before.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Linux skill level, if all else fails you could try using debugfs.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-ext3-ext4-deleted-files-recovery-howto.html

I have had luck with this in the past as an all else fails approach but make sure your try other solutions first as this has the ability to bork everything if you are not careful.

Comment: I didn't lose my files using rm command, and my USB file system was NTFS, will that still work?

Comment: no the fs needs to be ext2/3 to my knowledge

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to increase the chance of recovery refrain from doing any write operations, this include trying to 'fix', format and etc. If you really need to try those, make a full disk sector to sector image to do the recovery later on.

I had really good luck using R-Studio / GetDataBack. They are not free, but you could use the trial before buying. I wish I could recommend free/FOSS alternatives but from experience I don't think any of those really effective on recovering from low level format, especially when proprietary NTFS is being used.

Do a full disk scan and select NTFS to search, if the required informations were still intact, you might be able to recover the whole partition. If it couldn't find any partition those programs also offer specific file type recovery (e.g docx) by identifying the file signature, even when the disk is not initialised/still RAW.

Answer (score 0):

I had the most success with DiskDigger: http://diskdigger.org/ (free for personal use) 
In contrast to other recovery tools it does not need a partition to work on. It can scan a raw device. It only works if your partition was FAT (FAT12, FAT16, FAT32), NTFS, or exFAT.